# How to update a control in a user control in a tabpage in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, tabcontrol

I am a self learning student in VB.Net. I have created a user control with TabControl.
I have added it dynamically to a new TabControl while add button is clicked. But I don't know how to modify the content of the control in the user control. Kindly help me in accessing the control inside user control in a tabcontrol.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim a As string
    Dim b As Object

    Private Sub btnAddTabPage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddTabPage.Click
        Dim tabpage As New TabPage
        tabpage.Text = "USERPanel-" + n.ToString
        tabpage.Name = "USERTab-" + n.ToString
        tcUsers.TabPages.Add(tabpage)
        tcUsers.SelectedTab = tabpage
        n = n + 1

        'Dim lbltabname As Label = New Label
        'lbltabname.Text = tpUsers.SelectedTab.Name.ToString
        'tpUsers.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(lbltabname)
        Dim ctrl As Userdata = New Userdata
        ctrl.Name = "USERdata-" + n.ToString
        tcUsers.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(ctrl)
        ctrl.lblUserName.Text = tcUsers.SelectedTab.Name.ToString
        ctrl.lblUserAge.Text = tcUsers.SelectedTab.Text.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        n = 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDeleteTabPage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteTabPage.Click
        tcUsers.TabPages.Remove(tcUsers.SelectedTab)
    End Sub
End Class
```

For Eg.
I have a textbox in the user control. I need to modify the content of the text box.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing a child control of a user control. Only the user control should do that. The user control should have members of its own that pass through to the appropriate child members, e.g. a `TextBoxText` property that passes through to `TextBox1.Text` or a `ButtonClick` event that passes through to `Button1.Click`.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable comments. Will try this.